# using jquery and bootstrap in reactjs app returns errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I want to user jquery and boostrap with bootstrap.js in my react app.

bootstrap css works fine. But jquery and bootstrap.js not.

i've done the normal stuff

```
npm install --save jquery
```

and

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

is not working.

then I've added this:

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
```

and

```
import 'bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min'
```

but then I got this error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks at all

Comment: try to give `cdn` reference in `index.html` file, it will work, installing `jquery` is not required, use this reference: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: I added it to index like ths `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" />`' but now it is not compiling...

Comment: got this error `481:1   error    '$' is not defined                   no-undef
`

Comment: do you want to use `jquery` or you want to add reference because bootstrap requires it ?

Comment: both^^ I want to use the bootstrap.js functions like tooltip and so on

Comment: `error '$' is not defined no-undef` comes from eslint. add `/* global $ */` on top of your file with error.